# I am using doReturn in Mockito but I keep getting UnfinishedStubbingException error because I don't have thenReturn

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

When using `doReturn` in Mockito it doesn't have a `thenReturn` so I am confused why it keeps throwing an `UnfinishedStubbingException Unfinished stubbing detected here: E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.`. It is throwing that error for all my `doReturn`.

My code:

```
public List<Users> getUsers(String userId) {
    List<Users> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("users");
    ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.getIndex("userIndex").query(QuerySpec);
    Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        list.add(Util.jsonToObject(iterator.next().toJSONPretty(), Users.class));
    }
    return usersList;
}
```

Test class:

```
    List<Users> mockList = mock(List.class);
    Table mockTable = mock(Table.class);
    Users details = new Users("", "", "");
    ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> mockCollection = mock(ItemCollection.class);
    IteratorSupport<Item, QueryOutcome> mockIterator = mock(IteratorSupport.class);
    doReturn(mockTable).when(dynamoDB.getTable("users"));
    doReturn(mockCollection).when(mockTable.getIndex("")).query(mock(QuerySpec.class));
    doReturn(mockIterator).when(mockCollection).iterator();
    doReturn(true).doReturn(false).when(mockIterator).hasNext();
    doReturn(true).when(mockList).add(details);
    assertNotNull(dynamoService.getUser("").get(0));
```

Comment: Hint: A test should always use independent testdata. You should just mock your business-logic and not data layers and basic functions like lists/collections/... The only extern dependency you have here is the `dynamoDb` instance. That should be mocked. All other calles are basic functions you dont mock - just assert by comparing result data at the end. Just keep the scope small and clear.

Comment: @LenglBoy Yes I agree but Dynamodb testing makes it difficult to mock without mocking external dependency.

Comment: Depending on the `Table` object and complexity you can use a stub there as well - never the elss can you show the real full error trace as well?

Comment: How does the `dynamoDB` value get into the class that you're testing?  Your test suggests that you need this to be a mock, but you don't seem to be injecting a mock for it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The failure is the correct mockito grammar. So it is all about how you want you statements to be shown up and what your codestyle is about.
`doReturn` and `thenReturn` are more or less the same BUT used in different ways of accessing mocking statements.

```
// Gramar styled: code can be read like a book. Might be longer
doReturn("mockedResult").when(myMock).theMocksCalledMethod();

// Technical style: short but you might need to think about it shortly. Not intuitive
when(myMock.theMocksCalledMethod()).thenReturn("mockedResult");
```

So the conclusion is: you mixed up the styles and they are not 100% behaving the same way so you cant mix it up. Correct your syntak in one of those ways and it will work - even beside you mocked way to much :)

Comment: It definitly is since you mixed up the mock statements so that's why they are complaining about a missing `thenReturn` even if you have already declared a `doReturn`. Try to refactor the code, simplify mocking and rephrase your statements. If there is still a failure share the stacktrace as well and the new code.

Comment: @user21476047 specially take care of the brackets and when-statement combined with your matching phrase

Comment: This answer is correct.  The line with the problem is `doReturn(mockTable).when(dynamoDB.getTable("users"));` which has the `doReturn`, but doesn't have a method call after the `when`.  Perhaps it was intended to be `doReturn(mockTable).when(dynamoDB).getTable("users");` - it's really important to get those parentheses in the right places.